# Extension of previous problem, involving $\ell^p$ norm circles

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, functional-analysis

If you look at [this previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/interesting-taxicab-problem), I asked how to find the sum of all the areas between two taxicab geometry circles. However, upon learning about [$\ell^p$ norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Motivation), I thought it would be pretty interesting to extend the problem to all $\ell^p$ norm circles, not just $\ell^1$ (taxicab).

If $p=1$, then the result has already been found (the total area is $\frac{5k^2-k-4}{2}$). If $p = \infty$, then each "circle" is just a square, and the area is also easily found (I'm too tired to think about it, but I think it would just be $4(k^2-1)$). Is there, however, a general formula for the area of each circle and the total area of the regions between circles in terms of $k$ and $p$; that is, what is the equation for the area of each overlapping region?

The area of an individual circle, if I did it correctly, is the area of a Lamé curve with $r = p$ and a radius of $k-n$ (see the [linked problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/interesting-taxicab-problem)), which equals $\displaystyle 4(k-n)^2\frac{(\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{p})^2)}{\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{p})}$. This can be reduced to $\displaystyle 2(k-n)^2 \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{p})^2}{p \Gamma(\frac{2}{p})}$ (see equations 41 and 42 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html#eqn41)).

Here are some explanatory pictures:

$k=5, p=1$

[image: k=5, p=1]

$k=5, p=2$

[image: k=5, p=2]

$k=5, p=3$

[image: k=5, p=3]

Comment: added a simplification of the area... any ideas? I have not come up with any yet.

Comment: What is $n$ supposed to be?

Comment: FYI, in this context one usually uses lower-case l: $l^p$ or $\ell^p$.

Comment: @Nate: noted. will fix in a moment. @J.M. $n = 0, 1, \ldots , k-1$ (see the linked problem)

Comment: If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly, why can't you just subtract the total area of one Lamé curve from another?

Comment: @J. M. because they all have different centers.

Comment: I added pictures to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [superellipses](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html) would seem to fit your bill, as long as $p < \infty$.

Comment: alright, so I would get $A=4k^2\frac{(\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{p})^2)}{\Gamma(1+\frac{2}{p})}$. As far as I know there is no nice way of displaying that. Is that the only way to find the area?

Comment: @Eugene: I don't really think you can get it any simpler than as a ratio of gamma functions. In any event, general expressions for areas/volumes of balls will always require the gamma function.

Comment: fair enough. then is there a way to find the total area correctly? the overlap is done in such a way that it isn't obvious how to figure it out...

Comment: That's already the expression for the total area; the trick is to just compute the area of a single quadrant (i.e. have the area integral range from 0 to $\pi/2$) and then multiply the result by 4.

Comment: I meant the total area of a bunch of them overlapping; see the question I linked to in the original post (I edited it)